# awk : convert first line to first column and second line to second column

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file with data something like this :

```
{
MAG 121/002
Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018
MAG 121/003
Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018
MAG 121/004
Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018
}
```

I want the output as :

```
{
MAG 121/002 | Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018
MAG 121/003 | Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018
}
```

and so on.. Any help is appreciated.

What I tried was:

```
cat <filename> | awk '{printf "%s" (NR%2==0? RS:FS), $1}'
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: Inian's comment and my answer was having few seconds difference, so I left to OP to answer Inian question and I will undo my delete of post then.

Comment: what i tried is :

cat <filename> | awk '{printf "%s" (NR%2==0? RS:FS), $1}'
MAG 121/002 Sun
MAG 121/003 Wed

Comment: With sed: `sed '/MAG/{N;s/\n/ | /}' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

```
awk '/{/||/}/{print;next} /MAG/{val=$0;getline;print val OFS $0}' OFS=" | "  Input_file
```

Comment: @Kannan, please try now and let me know if this helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Solution with sed:

```
echo "MAG 121/002
Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018
MAG 121/003
Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018
MAG 121/004
Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018" | tr "\n" "|" | sed 's/|/ | /g' | sed -r 's/([^|]+\|[^|]+)\| /\1\n/g'
MAG 121/002 | Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018 
MAG 121/003 | Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018 
MAG 121/004 | Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Read and echo:

```
echo "MAG 121/002
Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018
MAG 121/003
Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018
MAG 121/004
Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018" | while read line ; do case $line in MAG*) echo -n $line "| " ;; *) echo $line ;; esac ; done 
MAG 121/002 | Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018
MAG 121/003 | Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018
MAG 121/004 | Wed Mar 14 00:00:00 2018
```

code formatted:

```
while read line
do
  case $line in 
    MAG*) echo -n $line "| " ;; 
       *) echo $line ;; 
  esac
done
```

Comment: It's best practice not to submit multiple answers where it's not needed.  This answer ought to be merged with your other one, highlighting each as an alternative solution within broadly similar contexts.

Comment: Why? They're independent of each other. You can either vote this down, that up, both down or both up or ignore both.